# Html5 canvas image with part of image background by on button click

Tags: javascript, canvas

what i have:

1) Static Image and many parts or you can say as component in the form of rectangle box ( around 25 rectangle box with text inside that box its a name).

2) I also have the coordinates of 25 rectangle box ( X1, Y1, X2, Y2) 
3) 7 roles button ( front end)

what i did till now:

I could cut the part of the image and display it but its not looking good by using this:

```
 canvas_Context.drawImage(img,16,242,60,62,16,242,60,62); //Sodium
 canvas_Context.drawImage(img,934,362,76,49,934,362,76,49); //duke
 canvas_Context.drawImage(img,243,204,274,263,243,204,274,263);
```

then show the cut part by:

```
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
    Window.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
```

Here is my question:
1) when i click on 1 role the rectangle that does not belong to that role should not be appeared.

2) when i click on another role i need the component which belong to that role only.
3) I dont want the image to be cut only that part colour has to be changed that is not the role.

Comment: Your question is unclear--at least to me. :-/  Could you try explaining again?

Comment: simple way to explain see i have 1 image. in that i have 25 rectangle. now when i click on 1 button i need one few rectangle to be displayed not other.

Comment: Have you tried to set up click events and then perform the appropriate actions after? Maybe a visual representation will be clearer

Comment: You can clear a rectangular area (like part of your image) using `context.clearRect(x,y,width,height);`

Comment: context.clearRect(x,y,width,height); this is for canvas id. hOW to do for an image . do i have to create an image object and then like this : img.context.clearRect(x,y,width,height) then i want that as an image i am using this function:window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image1", "width=1019, height=742");
   Window.document.write("<p>This is 'image'</p>");

Comment: cutting the part of the image and displaying it is fine but its not looking good i need it in reverse form . hide the other part or the component and display other.because its an s/w architecture.

Comment: finally i got the solution here it is:var canvas_Context=canvas.getContext("2d");
   var img = document.getElementById("StaticView");
   
   canvas.width  = 1150;
   canvas.height = 850;
   
   
   
    canvas_Context.drawImage(img,0,0); //Sodium
    canvas_Context.clearRect(934,362,76,49);
    
    canvas.style.visibility = "hidden";
    
    
    
   
    
   var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
   window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
   Window.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");